# Create a pod using kubernetes SDK for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I want to create a pod with the **python client SDK** (similar to kubectl run) that gives me results like the below:

```
kubectl run --rm --image $IMAGE --overrides="$OVERRIDES" --generator=run-pod/v1 -ti "$POD"
```

Any good examples? I can see some examples which use exec https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_exec.py but this requires to create the pod first and run exec, but does not run **"Interactive Terminal"** as the -ti flags in kubectl run.

The code below works only with sending remote command but not with interactive terminal even if we run command=['/bin/bash'] which shows the output as below.

```
    try:    
        #resp = stream(api_instance.connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec, podname, namespace='default', stderr=True, stdin=True, stdout=True, tty=True)
        stream(api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec, podname, namespace='default', stderr=True, stdin=False, stdout=True, tty=False)
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec: %s\n" % e)
    print(f"Pod created - cannot exec")
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the interactive terminal; can you just have the thing you want the pod to do be its `command:`?  What's the image you included in the question?

Comment: am building a script for troubleshooting that requires an interactive terminal. running a set of commands is not what am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work here using pseudo terminal. still having some issues after exiting the terminal.

I got it to work here. Still having some issues after exiting the terminal.
https://github.com/mohatb/python/blob/master/examples/exec_tty